# Unsubscribe users from Simplenews from a specific Newsletter category

Tags: 7, emails

I send newsletters from my Drupal-7 website using Simplenews module. I have a general category, that has all my site users and it is the category I use the most.
Although, some of the newsletters are sent to a smaller target group (women-only, men-only etc).
My problem is that when users click on the unsubscribe link from a newsletter that is not from my general category, then they unsubscribe from this category only and not the general.
What I want to achieve, is that when a user is unsubscribed from any newsletter category, to automatically unsubscribe him from the general category also.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work. Use hook_simplenews_unsubcribe_user which will

```
/**
 * Invoked if a user is unsubscribed from a newsletter.
 *
 * @param $subscriber
 *   The subscriber object including all subscriptions of this user.
 *
 * @param $subscription
 *   The subscription object for this specific unsubscribe action.
 *
 * @ingroup subscriber
 */
function hook_simplenews_unsubscribe_user($subscriber, $subscription) {

}
```

Add this in your custom module. I think $mail and $tid will be available in $subscrption variable.

```
function module_simplenews_unsubscribe_user($subscriber, $subscription) {
  simplenews_unsubscribe_user($mail, $tid, FALSE, 'website');//$tid -s your genral category tid.
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer!so, with the FALSE attribute, they unsubscribe automatically from the general category also? I want when they unsubscribe from any other category, to also get unsubscribed from my general category from my custom module